# C Macro variable

Tags: c

I came across a code segment which uses Macro. I have some confusions about that macro and need some help there to understand. Since the original code is very long, I just take out the part which I have question about:

The following is simplified code snippet which I have questions about:

```
#define OP1(ptr, save, rail)                           \
    do {                                               \
            FIX_CONN (v, ptr, rail);                   \
        ...                                            \
    }while(0);

int main()
{ 
   int v;
   ...
   OP1(ptr, save, rail);
}
```

My first question is why put a ";" after while(0)? I remember the purpose of do while(0) in macro is to make the macro works as normal function. I am confused whether I need to put ";" after while(0) or not?

My second question is about this "v" used in FIX_CONN. In this code, does the "v" gets passed from main function?

Comment: You might also consider showing `FIX_CONN` to provide more context. You can find it with (from the source directory): `grep -R FIX_CONN * | grep define`.

Comment: do while is a control statement in c, http://mathbits.com/MathBits/CompSci/looping/dowhile.htm. It ends with a semicolons because statements either end either a semicolon or a block, but the block came beforehand, do it needs the semicolon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C Macros literally work as text replacement before the code is compiled. So You don't need the semi-colon as you'll put a semicolon in your code when you write the macro name.

As this is just text replacement you can use variables that are current in your code when you call the macro. This is what is happening with the `v`. It's not being passed it's just there.

You can get gcc to do the text replacement so you can see what the file will look like after the text replacements. to do this use the -e option i.e `gcc -e -i <myFile> -o <outputFile>` you may need to comment out some of the `#inculde` (unless you are going to let gcc know where all your headers are).

The precompiler will turn your code into:

```
int main()
{ 
  int v;
  ...
  do {
    FIX_CONN (v, ptr, rail);
    ...
  } while (0);; // notice the two semicolons here
}
```

(obviously FIX_CONN will also be expanded by the precompiler assuming it's a macro)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Just to check my understanding is correct, you mean if I declare a variable in a function named A and call a macro named B inside function A. All the variables declared in the function A can be used for macro B?

Comment: Yes. The precompiled takes the text from your macro and moves it to where you called the macro.

Comment: You missed something. There are two semicolons after the `while (0)`, one from the macro expansion, and one from the `;` that follows the macro invocation. As I explained in my answer, that's harmless in this case, but it defeats the purpose of the `do ... while (0)` idiom.

Answer (score 2):

The `;` after the `while (0)` is a mistake by the author. It defeats the purpose of the `while(0)` idiom, which is to make the macro expansion valid in any context that requires a statement.

In this particular case, it's harmless. The macro is used at the end of `main`, where the expansion of `OP1(ptr, save, rail);` consists of a do-while loop followed by an empty statement.

The `v` in the macro definition is not *passed* from `main`. When the macro is expanded, the expansion refers to `v`, which happens to be visible at that point. If the macro were used outside `main`, either the compiler would report an error (because `v` is undeclared), or it would refer to some other `v` defined elsewhere. Having a macro, defined outside `main`, that refers to something that's visible only inside `main`, is arguably poor practice.